# Why things don't happen all at once?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, physics, quantum-physics

Why was there a time between Big Bang and now?

Why it did not happen all at once?

Why is there a delay between two changes?

Why delay (time) exists?

Why are not all changes compressed into extremely small time interval?

Why is max speed at which one thing can influence other(speed of Causality) 300,000 km/s?

Comment: Maybe it did happen all at once. Block universe is an idea

Comment: "*Time exists so that everything doesn't happen all at once, space exists so that it doesn't all happen to you.*" Susan Sontag. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know why. We have determined the speed of light through observations and experiments, but we don't know why the speed is what it is, or why the Universe is the way it is. The only part of your question that can be answered is the third- there is a delay between two changes because if there was not it would be a single change.